# Why I am getting None in place of int from if block inside a method called by another method in the class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code, I am trying to get a binary search result using a method inside the class. The class has more functions but only this function is giving the wrong output (`None` in place an integer). The `if` part from line number 10 to 15 is causing the problem.

```
class Solution:
    def getNum(self, nums, x):
        L_nums = len(nums)
        j = self.binary_search( nums, 0, L_nums-1, x)
        print("j=",j)
   
   
    def binary_search(self, nums, start, end, x):
        print("BS called  start=>", start,"end=>", end,"x=>", x)
        if end==start:
            if nums[end]==x:
                return end
            else:
                print("called else and returing -1")
                return -1
        i = (end-start)//2 + start
        print("i=",i)
        if x==nums[i]:
            return i
        elif x>nums[i]:
            self.binary_search(nums, i+1, end, x)
        else:
            self.binary_search(nums, start, i-1, x)


sol = Solution()
sol.getNum([1,3,5,7,9],1)
```

**output:** here `j` should be 0, in place of that it is returning None

```
BS called  start=> 0 end=> 4 x=> 1
i= 2
BS called  start=> 0 end=> 1 x=> 1
i= 0
j= None
```

Comment: yes, the solution can be applied to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer to your question: include the "return" in raw 21,23.

20. ```
       elif x>nums[i]:
    ```
21. ```
           return self.binary_search(nums, i+1, end, x)
    ```
22. ```
       else:
    ```
23. ```
           return self.binary_search(nums, start, i-1, x)
    ```